# Java Arraylist remove object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, lwjgl

Everytime a box, from the arraylist shapes, reaches a specified position, it has to be removed from the arraylist. But it doesn't seems to work, what's im doing wrong?

```
if(!box.removing && box.y == MoveY - 50 && MoveX != box.x) {
                    box.removing = true;
                    score += 10;

                    System.out.println(shapes.indexOf(box));

                    shapes.remove(shapes.indexOf(box));


                } else {
                    // Gravity loop, if not reached the position. This work.
                    box.update(1);
                }
```

Comment: shapes.indexOf(box) is giving correct value ?

Comment: Lol ;) You asked me if "shapes.indexOf(box) is giving correct value" i said yes mate ;)

Answer (score 2):

The List type supports a variant of ".remove()" that takes the object, itself, as a parameter, so you don't need to find its index first and then remove by index. That being said, this operation is relatively expensive for type ArrayList; if you are inserting/removing at arbitrary locations, use LinkedList.

Comment: Interesting, any thoughts on, how to implement that in this?

Comment: Err... you can just to shapes.remove(box) instead of shapes.remove(shapes.indexOf(box)), but you should use a LinkedList type instead of an ArrayList type to make it more performant.

Comment: Well, thanks for that suggestion. It sort of work, but not really. I mean, it remove the first two, and then when the third hits, it crash.